# Quadratic extension field (or complex numbers) with OpenSSL's BN?

Tags: c, openssl, bignum, elliptic-curve

Does OpenSSL have any support for operations in the quadratic extension field (or, alternatively, operations with complex numbers) using the BN API?

If not, are there any other open source libraries that do?

Comment: I do not remember any library dealing with complex integers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at [PBC](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/). This is a library for computing pairings on some elliptic curves, which implies using field extensions of various degrees, including quadratic extensions for some fields.